# External Services : Unable to map response Error

Tags: visual-workflow, external-services

I'm working on a flow that can search confluence using external services.

I can search successfully via postman.  I am able to hit confluence via external services and obtain data but the flow throws an unhandled fault when parsing the response:

Error Occurred: Unable to map response for parameter: 200 and invokable action: Confluence5.getRestApiContentSearch.

I have reviewed the response and the schema definition and as far as I can tell it does match up.  I will post the definition and the response at the end of this post, in case there is something obvious I am missing.  I have also posted them as gists on github if its easier to read
[request](https://gist.github.com/goravseth/d9b6f6b3330c56ae8a5d670d26c70cd1)
[response](https://gist.github.com/goravseth/ff56ea3b495aaca25c0bb4cbd66d240b)

The only thing that i have noticed in the schema is that Restrictions is an empty object.

```
   "definitions": {
        "Restrictions": {},
        "_links": {.....
```

In the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.external_services_schema.htm&type=5) it says "A property must include a value" but i'm not sure of the implications of that.  Any suggestions on what to look for or test would be appreciated.

The flow is just a proof of concept and only runs the external service action and does not reference the response at all.

[image: screenshot of flow]

SCHEMA

```
{
   "swagger": "2.0",
   "info": {
      "description": "defaultDescription",
      "version": "0.1",
      "title": "confluence search"
   },
   "paths": {
      "/rest/api/content/search": {
         "get": {
            "produces": [
               "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters": [
               {
                  "name": "limit",
                  "in": "query",
                  "required": false,
                  "type": "string",
                  "x-example": "2"
               },
               {
                  "name": "cql",
                  "in": "query",
                  "required": false,
                  "type": "string",
                  "x-example": "space=sfdc"
               }
            ],
            "responses": {
               "200": {
                  "description": "Definition generated from Swagger Inspector",
                  "schema": {
                     "$ref": "#/definitions/Model0"
                  }
               }
            },
            "security": [
               {
                  "Secured": []
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "securityDefinitions": {
      "Secured": {
         "type": "basic"
      }
   },
   "definitions": {
      "Restrictions": {},
      "_links": {
         "properties": {
            "webui": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "tinyui": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "self": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      },
      "_expandable": {
         "properties": {
            "container": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "metadata": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "extensions": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "operations": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "children": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "history": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "ancestors": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "body": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "version": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "descendants": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "space": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      },
      "Results": {
         "properties": {
            "id": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "type": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "status": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "title": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "restrictions": {
               "$ref": "#/definitions/Restrictions"
            },
            "_links": {
               "$ref": "#/definitions/_links"
            },
            "_expandable": {
               "$ref": "#/definitions/_expandable"
            }
         }
      },
      "Model0links": {
         "properties": {
            "self": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "next": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "base": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "context": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      },
      "Model0": {
         "properties": {
            "results": {
               "type": "array",
               "items": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/Results"
               }
            },
            "start": {
               "type": "integer",
               "format": "int32"
            },
            "limit": {
               "type": "integer",
               "format": "int32"
            },
            "size": {
               "type": "integer",
               "format": "int32"
            },
            "cqlQuery": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "searchDuration": {
               "type": "integer",
               "format": "int32"
            },
            "totalSize": {
               "type": "integer",
               "format": "int32"
            },
            "_links": {
               "$ref": "#/definitions/Model0links"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

RESPONSE THAT THROWS ERROR (COPIED FROM FLOW DEBUGGER AND FORMATTED)

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "id":"86573808",
         "type":"page",
         "status":"current",
         "title":"Tasks",
         "restrictions":{
            
         },
         "_links":{
            "webui":"/display/SFDC/Tasks",
            "tinyui":"/x/8AIpBQ",
            "self":"https://confluence.ashoka.org/rest/api/content/86573808"
         },
         "_expandable":{
            "container":"",
            "metadata":"",
            "extensions":"",
            "operations":"",
            "children":"",
            "history":"/rest/api/content/86573808/history",
            "ancestors":"",
            "body":"",
            "version":"",
            "descendants":"",
            "space":"/rest/api/space/SFDC"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"90210910",
         "type":"page",
         "status":"current",
         "title":"documentation migration plan and training plan",
         "restrictions":{
            
         },
         "_links":{
            "webui":"/display/SFDC/documentation+migration+plan+and+training+plan",
            "tinyui":"/x/XoJgBQ",
            "self":"https://confluence.ashoka.org/rest/api/content/90210910"
         },
         "_expandable":{
            "container":"",
            "metadata":"",
            "extensions":"",
            "operations":"",
            "children":"",
            "history":"/rest/api/content/90210910/history",
            "ancestors":"",
            "body":"",
            "version":"",
            "descendants":"",
            "space":"/rest/api/space/SFDC"
         }
      }
   ],
   "start":0,
   "limit":2,
   "size":2,
   "cqlQuery":"space=SFDC and type=page",
   "searchDuration":24,
   "totalSize":19,
   "_links":{
      "self":"https://confluence.ashoka.org/rest/api/content/search?cql=space%3DSFDC+and+type%3Dpage",
      "next":"/rest/api/content/search?limit=2&start=2&cql=space%3DSFDC+and+type%3Dpage",
      "base":"https://confluence.ashoka.org",
      "context":""
   }
}
```

Comment: logged premier support ticket last week, no progress yet.